# Why reputation will decrease?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why will the reputation decrease when the supported user was removed?

Comment: check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126470/224252

Comment: @Marius, ok sir, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty much explained [here](http://:https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed) in the help from MSE.

> This message means that a user who voted for one of your posts had
>   their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the
>   network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were
>   removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone.
>   The resultant reputation change could be any amount; it could even be
>   a reputation gain if enough of the removed votes were downvotes. All
>   the reputation changes from a single user's deletion are rolled into a
>   single event in the reputation page labelled "User was removed".
>
> This removal occurs whenever a user is deleted, unless that user had a
>   very high reputation score. Because high-reputation users have usually
>   cast a great many votes, removing all of them could be that much more
>   disruptive to other users. In such cases, the staff use a special
>   deletion that preserves the votes, resulting in no reputation change
>   for those who had been voted on by that user.